# Remove Duplicates from Sorted Array from leetcode, why it wrong answer？

Tags: c++

this is Remove Duplicates from Sorted Array from leetcode
   the right answer is

```
   class Solution {
public:
    /**
     * @param A: a list of integers
     * @return : return an integer
     */
    int removeDuplicates(vector<int> &nums) {
        // write your code here
        int i=1;
        while(i<nums.size()){
            if(nums[i] != nums[i-1])
                ++i;
            else
                nums.erase(nums.begin()+i);
        }
        return nums.size();
    }
};
```

I change this code like these

```
class Solution {
public:
    int removeDuplicates(vector<int>& nums) {
        int i = 1;
        while( i < nums.size()) {
            if( nums[i] != nums[i+1])
            i++;
            else
            nums.erase(nums.begin() + i);
        }
        return nums.size();
    }
};
```

I don't know why it‘s wrong,  Input:  [1,1] Output: [1,1]  Expected:[1]

and like this:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int removeDuplicates(vector<int>& nums) {
        for(int i = 1; i < nums.size(); i++) {
            if( nums[i-1] = nums[i])
            nums.erase(nums.begin() + i);
        }
        return nums.size();
    }
};
```

Input:
[1,2]
Output:
[2]
Expected:
[1,2]

Comment: You need to increment i  in the of outside conditions yet inside while, beside you need to start from zero. not from 1 . vectors are like arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing a vector is zero-based (just like for the built-in low level arrays), so set the initial value of i to zero (instead of 1).  In professional code I'd expect this to be done by using the standard sort and unique algorithms against the vector.

Comment: for(int i = 1; i < nums.size(); i++) {
            if( nums[i-1] = nums[i])
            nums.erase(nums.begin() + i);
        }
        return nums.size();
 still wrong.[1,2] =>[2]

Comment: Input:
[1,1,1]
Output:
[1,1]
Expected:
[1]

Comment: Don't ++ the i when an item is erased, maybe?